# Proof of combinatorial set

Tags: combinatorics

How to give a combinatorial proof from

$$\sum_{i=1}^n {n\choose i}^2={2n\choose n}$$

I have tried to give an argument with 2n set elements colored red but i got stuck on this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. Please try to use MathJax to format the mathematical phrases and equation so that would be easier to read. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and critical!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the number of ways to colour $n$ elements from $2n$ red and the others blue. This is clearly the RHS.

Now split the $2n$ into two equally sized groups. In the first group, choose $i$ elements to colour red and make the rest blue. In the second group, choose $i$ elements to colour blue and make the rest red. Summing over all $i$ gives the number of ways to colour $n$ objects red and we are done.